# php is null when empty?

Tags: php, null

I have a question regarding `NULL` in PHP:

```
  $a = '';
  if($a == NULL) {
      echo 'is null';
  }
```

Why do I see **is null** when `$a` is an empty string? Is that a bug?

Answer (score 383, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
if($variable === NULL) {...}
```

Note the `===`.
When use `==`, as you did, PHP treats *NULL*, *false*, *0*, the *empty* string, and *empty* arrays as equal.

Comment: False, your condition only matches uninitialized and null ```$variable```.
What you want is actually: ```$variable == null``` (note the ```==```)

Comment: @ThomasLAURENT, that's what the OP was looking for, they were wondering why `== null` was matching the empty string and not just null or undefined.

Comment: Oups my mistake, but your last sentence led me think NULL, false, 0 and "" were **strictly** equal which is wrong, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I noticed this answer is from 2011. Is this still true in 2016?

Comment: @James it's an intended behaviour in PHP, it's still true even in 2017 and will be true for a long time I suppose

Comment: `$a = ''` is an empty `string`, `false` is a boolean, `$a = 0;` is an integer and `null` is from type `null`. What OP is telling is that PHP will thread them as "same" in value, but not as "same" in type. So a *strict* `===` check will also check for type and fail if you use different ones. That's the reason you should be consistence in your return values. If you normaly return a string in a method like `getName()`, you shouldn't get `null` when it's empty, but more likely an emtpy *string* `$user->getName() === ''` or `$user->getId() === 0` or `$user->isActive === false`. Intended behaviour!

Comment: Beeing inconsistent results in type errors which are the most argument from people that dislike PHP. In facts it's pretty easy.. just don't mix types and be consistent. If you don't know what type you will receive, you check before inserting it (don't let your Entity become invalid by inserting wrong types). Just wanted to add that for people coming back here in future. This probally won't change in the future, like I said, it's intended behaviour and most logical. If you mix them and don't be inconsting.. the real sorcery starts! Like in Javascript (google: javascript  nanana batman "wat")

Comment: I've edited the answer's final sentence(s), to avoid the confusion Thomas Laurent had at first.

Answer (score 259):

As is shown in the following table, `empty($foo)` is equivalent to `$foo==null` and `is_null($foo)` has the same function of `$foo===null`. The table also shows some tricky values regarding the `null` comparison. (ϕ denotes an uninitialized variables. )

```
         empty    is_null 
         ==null  ===null  isset   array_key_exists
      ϕ |   T   |   T   |   F   |   F   
   null |   T   |   T   |   F   |   T   
     "" |   T   |   F   |   T   |   T   
     [] |   T   |   F   |   T   |   T
      0 |   T   |   F   |   T   |   T      
  false |   T   |   F   |   T   |   T   
   true |   F   |   F   |   T   |   T   
      1 |   F   |   F   |   T   |   T   
     \0 |   F   |   F   |   T   |   T
```

Comment: Missing "0" and "0.0" in the table. They make things really tricky, especially empty(). That's why I avoid using empty().

Comment: @PHPst Base on the table that you shown, so what is actually the php code of what you called 'simple comparison'?

Comment: @hyip `==null`and `===null`.

Comment: This should be the top answer, much more complete. Thanks.

Comment: @PHPst You said that simple comparison is less ambiguous. Can you please provide an example of using simple comparison instead of these NULL empty() etc.

Comment: isset is the most useful function. when I found out that in php false == null returns true.... I can't even.. that's just plain stupid

Answer (score 35):

check `==` vs `===`

`'' == NULL` would return true
`0 == NULL` would return true
`false == null` would return true

where as

`'' === NULL` would return false
`0 === NULL` would return false
`false === NULL` would return false

Comment: Tested and correct. ''==null (true) while ''===null(false)

Answer (score 20):

No it's not a bug. Have a look at the [*Loose comparisons with ==* table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) (second table), which shows the result of comparing each value in the first column with the values in the other columns:

```
    TRUE    FALSE   1       0       -1      "1"     "0"     "-1"    NULL    array() "php"   ""

    [...]    

""  FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
```

There you can see that an empty string `""` compared with `false`, `0`, `NULL` or `""` will yield true.

You might want to use [`is_null` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) instead, or strict comparison (third table).

Comment: The Loose comparisons table seems to suggest that comparing 0=="php" or "php"==0 will both yield true. What is going on there?

Comment: @Robert: A string not starting with digits is converted to `0` when cast to a string: http://codepad.org/qi40SG3E. So `(int)"php" == 0`.

Comment: @Robert: I meant *"when cast to a **number**"*.

Answer (score 13):

This **is not** a bug but PHP normal behavior. It happens because the `==` operator in PHP doesn't check for type.

```
'' == null == 0 == false
```

If you want also to check if the values have the same type, use `===` instead. To study in deep this difference, please read the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score 10):

PHP 7 isset() vs empty() vs is_null()

[image]

Answer (score 9):

If you use `==`, php treats an empty string or array as `null`. To make the distinction between `null` and `empty`, either use `===` or `is_null`. So:

`if($a === NULL)` or `if(is_null($a))`

Comment: if($a === NULL)

Answer (score 0):

Just to addon if someone is dealing with `&nbsp;`, this would work if dealing with `&nbsp;`.

Replace it with `str_replace()` first and check it with `empty()`

```
empty(str_replace("&nbsp;" ,"" , $YOUR_DATA)) ? $YOUR_DATA = '--' : $YOUR_DATA;
```

Answer (score 0):

**NULL** stands for a variable without value. To check if a variable is NULL you can either use `is_null($var)` or the comparison (`===`) with **NULL**. Both ways, however, generate a warning if the variable is not defined. Similar to `isset($var)` and `empty($var)`, which can be used as functions.

```
var_dump(is_null($var)); // true
var_dump($var === null); // true
var_dump(empty($var)); // true
```

Read more in [How to check if a variable is NULL in PHP?](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-null-in-php/)

Answer (score -1):

Use `empty` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php.

Example:

```
$a = '';
if(empty($a)) {
    echo 'is empty';
}
```