# Passing 0 to database but not an empy text input

Tags: php, mysql

I am passing user entered numerical values into a database using text inputs.  I want the db to execute the insert for all numerical values greater than or equal to 0 however if nothing is in the textbox I do not want the database to execute the insert.  So I would like to distinguish between 0 and no entry.  isset would still return true.  any help would be great
Thank You

I have my code written, I just need help with the logic test of determining whether zero or null.

Comment: Please add your relevant code and we will have a look.

Comment: What have you got so far? Have you tried just a simple if($item != '' && $item != null)

Comment: you can check for $_POST['text'] === ''

Comment: @Orangepill yes but it would still pass on `""` which would be the same as `!isset`

Comment: @prix yep... just throwing out alternatives

Comment: @Orangepill [one of my favorite topics about this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15607549/342740)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `isset` in this case as it will detect if the textbox is null or not set however it will pass if it is 0

```
if (isset($_POST['textbox']))
```

You can further combine it with `strlen` like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['textbox']) && strlen($_POST['textbox']) > 0)
```