# PHP echo no text if $name is not filled in or == 0 else echo $name

Tags: php, html

PHP echo no text if $name is not filled in or == 0 else echo $name

For example here's what I have:

```
<?php
if ($name == 0)
{ 
echo $name;
}
else
{
echo "Nothing here.";
?>
```

Comment: Don't forget the closing brace for `echo "Nothing here.";` - Plus, where is `$name` being defined? Your question in unclear.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (empty($name))
{ 
  echo "Nothing here.";
}
else
{
  echo $name; 
}
?>
```

empty() -> Gives True if ist emty!

Comment: `is_emty` you sure about that?

Comment: Um... do read the manual again. I know it very well, and it's not `is_emty` nor `emty`

Comment: I dont now why Im still doing that mistake :(

Comment: The syntax is `bool empty ( mixed $var )` and not `bool emty ( mixed $var )`

Comment: oh havent seen that spelling mistake - Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I chose not to submit an answer based on the question being unclear, because we have no indication as to where `$name` is being defined, nor do we know if the value is based on an integer, or a string, or from a form, who knows. We shall wait for the OP's response to your answer. Technically, you are correct, however I rather wait for the OP to respond to my comment left under the question.

Answer (score 0):

check if this is working:

```
<?php
if ($name == 0)
    {echo "Nothing here";}
else
    {echo $name;}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [php is null or empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236354/php-is-null-or-empty)

The code should be

```
<?php
if ($name === NULL) {
    echo "Nothing here.";
} else {
    echo $name;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try

```
<?php
echo empty($name)? 'Nothing here.' : $name;
?>
```

empty() return true means $name is null, 0 or not defined.