# PHP didn't see hard setup value for input when it is disabled

Tags: php, html, forms

But... One problem is still appear. When I set up value for hard in HTML:

[image]

```
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="field">
      <input name="subject_field" id="subject_field" placeholder="Temat" value="Testing" disabled>
      <label class="icon" for="subject_field">
        <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My PHP code didn't see that in this field is something inside.

I want to have input for subject/topic and selection for subject/topic. I will be comment one of them if I don't need them. But also I want to have third variant - input for subject/topic with hard setup setup value. But this not working as I except.

Now that is the main problem. Why? And how to resolve this one. It is very important for me. Please advice.

---

**UNDER IS THE MAIN QUESTION - one problem was solved by me.**

---

Ok, I have to edit my question because I see that nobody can not understand me.

Well, so again:
I have very low knowledge about PHP, but even so I created simply contact form only in PHP. It works very well but I would like to upgrade it and I don't know how.

That contact form looks that:

[image]

It is in Polish because I from Poland. I am asking here because we do not have in Poland place like this for asking help.

Now, what I would like to change? You can see field named "Temat" (well it is not name, but placeholder)? It means Topic. Now everybody can topic message as they want. I want to change it and set up "hard" topics. Then everybody will only can choice my topics. So what is the problem?

Even if I now setup hard "topic" via "value=something" (in HTML) then PHP thinks that this field is empty and of course return error. I have to setup variable in PHP code.

I suppose if I now create new field for list choice then PHP still will be think that field is empty. And I don't want to create variables for each topic. I would like to setup PHP for reading what is in field and setup variable by self.

Now here I don't know what to do and how. Because I am newbie. Don't tell me go back to book and learn whole PHP. Please advice.

Here is code of PHP: https://github.com/IdolwSzutrab7/Contact-Form/blob/master/submit.php It is little long and I don't know to paste it here or not?

```
<?php
function died($error) {
    echo '<p><h2>Wystąpił problem z działaniem skryptu.</h2></p>';
    echo '<p>Wykryto następujące błędy:<ul>'.$error.'</ul></p>';
    echo '<p>Wiadomośc nie została wysłana.</p>';
    echo '<p><a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Kliknij tutaj</a>, aby wrócić i spróbować ponownie.</p>';
    //echo '<p><a href="javascript:window.close()">Kliknij tutaj</a>, aby zamknąć kartę i spróbuj ponownie..</p>';
    die();
};
function done() {
  echo '<p><h1>Wiadomość została wysłana.</h1></p>';
}
if ( isset($_POST) ) {
  // Adresat
  $do         = 'XXX'; // Adres e-Mail na który ma zostać wysłany formularz
  // Dane formularza
  $imie       = $_POST['name_field'];
  $email      = $_POST['address_field'];
  $telefon    = $_POST['phone_field'];
  $firma      = $_POST['company_field'];
  $temat      = $_POST['subject_field'];
  $wiadomosc  = $_POST['message_field'];
  $captcha    = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
  // Nagłówek wiadomości e-Mail
  $headers = array('From: "'.$imie.'" <'.$email.'>',
                   'Reply-To: '.$email,
                   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . PHP_VERSION);
  $headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);
  // ReCaptcha NoCaptcha
  $secret = "XXX";
  if (!$captcha) {
    died('<li>Proszę wypełnić formularz reCAPTCHA.</li>');
    exit;
  }
  $response=json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), true);
  // Wytyczne do sprawdzenia danych
  $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  $imie_exp = "/^[A-Za-z ęóąśłżźćńĘÓĄŚŁŻŹĆŃ]+$/";
  $telefon_exp = "/^[0-9 ]+$/";

  // Sprawdzanie formularza w poszukiwaniu błędów
  if ($response['success'] == false) { // Tutaj sprawdza, czy reCAPtCHa zwraca success
    died('<li>Walidacja reCAPTCHA nie przeszła poprawnie!<br />Twoje działanie zostało zarejestrowane, a dane przesłane do administratora.</li>');
    exit;
  } else if (  !isset($_POST['name_field'])    ||
               !isset($_POST['address_field']) ||
               !isset($_POST['message_field']) ) { // Tutaj jest bloczek, który sprawdza czy dane pola są uzupełnione
    died('<li>Nie wszystkie wymagane pola zostały wypełnione.</li>');       
  } else if ( !preg_match($email_exp,$email) ) { // Tutaj sprawdza, czy e-Mail jest poprawnie uzupełniony
    died('<li>Adres e-Mail nie wygląda na autentyczny.</li>');
  } else if ( !preg_match($imie_exp,$imie) ) { // Tutaj sprawdza, czy Imię lub Nick nie zawiera jakichś dziwnych znaków
    died('<li>Imię lub Nick zawiera nienaturalne znaki.</li>');
  } else if ( !preg_match($telefon_exp,$telefon) && !$telefon == null ) { // Tutaj sprawdza, czy telefon zawiera cyfry tylko wtedy, gdy jest coś wpisane [inaczej widzi pole ktore jest ukryte i trkatuje je jako blad]
    died('<li>Numer telefonu powinien zawierać wyłącznie cyfry.');
  } else if ( strlen($wiadomosc) < 10 || strlen($wiadomosc)>1000 ) { // Tutaj sprawdza długość wiadomości
    died('<li>Wiadomość jest zbyt krótka lub zbyt długa.');
  } else if ( strlen($imie)>50    ||
              strlen($email)>50   ||
              strlen($telefon)>50 ||
              strlen($firma)>50   ||
              strlen($temat)>100 ) { // Tutaj jest bloczek, który sprawdza długość poszczególnych pól
    died('<li>Przekroczono maksymalną ilość znaków w niektórych polach.</li>');
  } else { done(); mail($do, $temat, $wiadomosc, $headers); };
} else { 
  died('<li>Nastąpiło nieoczekiwane zatrzymanie skryptu!</li>');
};
?>
```

And here is code of form in HTML: https://github.com/IdolwSzutrab7/Contact-Form/blob/master/index.php It is also little long.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>



<style>
body, html {margin:0;padding:0;}
#contact_form {
  width: 600px;;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  background: white;
  background: url('https://zotabox.com/media/core/image/gallery/simplepopup/1d.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
} #contact_form div.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
} #contact_form div.field {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
} #contact_form div.field input, #contact_form div.field textarea {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: black;
} #contact_form div.field input:hover, #contact_form div.field input:focus,
#contact_form div.field textarea:hover, #contact_form div.field textarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
} #contact_form div.field #submit_button {
  width: auto;
} #contact_form div.field #submit_button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
} #contact_form div.field .icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: 7px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  cursor: text;
} #contact_form div.field input:hover + .icon, #contact_form div.field input:focus + .icon,
#contact_form div.field textarea:hover + .icon, #contact_form div.field textarea:focus + .icon {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
</style>

<form id="contact_form" method="post" action="submit.php">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="field">
      <input name="name_field" id="name_field" placeholder="Twój nick lub imię">
      <label class="icon" for="name_field">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <input name="address_field" id="address_field" placeholder="Twój adres e-Mail">
      <label class="icon" for="address_field">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="field" style="display: none;">
      <input name="phone_field" id="phone_field" placeholder="Twój numer telefonu">
      <label class="icon" for="phone_field">
        <i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="field"  style="display: none;">
      <input name="company_field" id="company_field" placeholder="Firma">
      <label class="icon" for="company_field">
        <i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="field">
      <input name="subject_field" id="subject_field" placeholder="Temat">
      <label class="icon" for="subject_field">
        <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="field">
    <textarea name="message_field" id="message_field" placeholder="Tutaj wpisz treść swojej wiadomości..." rows="7" maxlength="1000" spellcheck="true"></textarea>
      <label class="icon" for="message_field">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="field">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfnGigTAAAAAGsECHWJRKpajpJI0SYt24XFy8S-"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field" style="text-align: right;"><div style="display: inline-block; position: relative;">
    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Wyślij">
      <label class="icon" for="submit_button" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </label>
    </div></div>
  </div>
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Well... When I setup value for "hard" like this:

[image]

Then I have to setup variable for "hard" in PHP, like this:

[image]

Otherwise PHP return error while send form.

I am sure at 90% that same situation will be when I add selection field in the form - I mean PHP will not recognize choice from selection. That is the problem.

Hmm... I think I found what is wrong. My PHP code only check if the value of specified fields are set. Not if they contains something. Even if value is empty for PHP it means it is set. Please look at this section:

```
if (  !isset($_POST['name_field'])    ||
               !isset($_POST['address_field']) ||
               !isset($_POST['message_field']) )
```

So now the main question is how to rebuild it for checking if these values contains something not checking if they are set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
  <input name="subject_field" id="subject_field" placeholder="Temat" value="Testing" disabled>
```

should be:

```
  <input name="subject_field" id="subject_field" placeholder="Temat" value="Testing" readonly>
```

The disabled function in your code won't post the input value of "subject_field" to the PHP file.

Comment: I will immediately check this. I will back when I check it. Thx. I didn't know that "readonly" o.O

Comment: Okay. Try it and let me know whether its working or not.

Comment: WTF? It is working! :D Simply solutions always resolve big problems :D Thx you very much. :)

Comment: haha.. i also had encountered this problem. Welcome.. Good Luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a selection so you just add a select tag in your html forms, just a simple as that. Also make sure that your value in selection correspond to your selection list.Below is the code

```html
<select>
  <option value="topic1">Topic 1</option>
  <option value="topic2">Topic 2</option>
  <option value="topic3">Topic 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what about PHP? You didn't understand me. I know how to create selection in HTML. I have excellent knowledge about HTML. But not about PHP. I am sure that this is not enough for PHP. Please check my PHP code. It is checking fields. If they are empty then return error. I think if I create select list like yours then will return error.

Comment: @BartoszIdolwSzutrab7W _excellent knowledge about HTML_ and putting `style` outside of head? ;)

Comment: so its mean that you want to create a selection in php? I dont understand your question but if you want to make a selection in php just make it like this 
<?php echo '<select>
  <option value="topic1">Topic 1</option></select>';?>

Comment: @bub, yes, but this is only for you guys. Normally I write websites different. You can check source code of my main website http://isvn.pl/

Comment: @miorfarhan, no, I want to create selection in HTML, but this is not important here. The problem is that PHP will be think that field (ours selection) is empty. I want to make this selection as important field so PHP have to check this field but when user change topic then I want to have it saved in PHP code - so PHP have to read that field (ours selection). I don't know how to do it.

Comment: oh, so that mean you have to validate your input before you submit the form, create one file validation.php, in the file you have to code for validate that the input is selected or not, if the selection is empty then it will return an error msg like "Please select the choice below!"

Comment: @miorfarhan, yes, exactly. I already have validation in my PHP code, please check. Now everything works good, but when I change that "topic" field with "value=Something" and disable it with "disabled=disabled" then PHP thinks that this field is empty - but is not empty, because i setup "value" argument. I am 100% sure that it will be same situation when I add selection field. That is why I am asking here for help. I have to change PHP code for that fields with setuped "value=something" or selection (in the future) are not empty.

Comment: added some screenshot to question. Please check them.

Comment: $min_length = 1;
$len = mb_strlen($temat, 'UTF-8');
return ($len < $min_length) ? $error_text : "valid";

try to add this in your validation so that we will know that it is empty or have character inside

Comment: also if you have declare a value inside subject_field, usually it will pass the value to php

Comment: I add answer to my question. Please check it because there some problems are solved some not.

Comment: @bub, also someone as a "newbie" can not create so tidy and nice form in HTML like my. That is good proof that I know what I do (with HTML of course).

Answer (score 0):

Well... I think I resolve my problem (and appear another, please read to the end), but please check me and confirm.

I also give you test link but please don't spam too much - http://ts.isvn.pl/contactform/

The problem was from beginning with PHP code (I supposed that) but I didn't know where. I star thinking about that and I found:

[image]

```
  } else if (  !isset($_POST['name_field']) ||
               !isset($_POST['address_field']) ||
               !isset($_POST['subject_field']) ||
               !isset($_POST['message_field'])) { // Tutaj jest bloczek, który sprawdza czy dane pola są uzupełnione
    died('<li>Nie wszystkie wymagane pola zostały wypełnione.</li>');       
  }
```

I read a few interesting questions here at stackoverflow (i.e. "[php is null or empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236354/php-is-null-or-empty)") and understand that what I had was wrong. Again I started thinking about that and start changing. I found working solution:

[image]

```
  } else if (  $imie == NULL ||
               $email == NULL ||
               $temat == NULL ||
               $wiadomosc == NULL ) { // Tutaj jest bloczek, który sprawdza czy dane pola są uzupełnione
    died('<li>Nie wszystkie wymagane pola zostały wypełnione.</li>');       
  }
```

But that was not finish. I told you that I want my form modular. Some of fields I would like to turn on and turn off. I used just display: none in HTML:

[image]

```
  <div class="flex" style="display: none;">
    <div class="field">
      <input name="subject_field" id="subject_field" placeholder="Temat" value="Testing" disabled>
      <label class="icon" for="subject_field">
        <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But... For people like me this is hidden. But not for PHP code. I had to comment these lines. Otherwise PHP code still saw this code.

[image]

```
<!--
  <div class="flex" style="display: none;">
    <div class="field">
      <input name="subject_field" id="subject_field" placeholder="Temat" value="Testing" disabled>
      <label class="icon" for="subject_field">
        <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
-->
```

So bad but I can handle this.

But... One problem is still appear. When I set up value for hard in HTML:

[image]

```
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="field">
      <input name="subject_field" id="subject_field" placeholder="Temat" value="Testing" disabled>
      <label class="icon" for="subject_field">
        <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My PHP code didn't see that in this field is something inside.

I want to have input for subject/topic and selection for subject/topic. I will be comment one of them if I don't need them. But also I want to have third variant - input for subject/topic with hard setup setup value. But this not working as I except.

Now that is the main problem. Why? And how to resolve this one. It is very important for me. Please advice.

I am post it as a answer because I resolve some of my problems and this message is too long for put it in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why you have to make it like these
`$imie == NULL ||
               $email == NULL ||
               $temat == NULL ||
               $wiadomosc == NULL`

Comment: send me your full file, i try it on my server.

Comment: everything is on github. I give you links in my main question (before code). Or you can copy whole code. Whatever. But remember to put some secretcode or disable it from ReCaptcha NoCaptcha. Otherwise PHP code will be terminate.