# How to check if any variables are set?

Tags: php

checking if *all* are set

```
if(
    isset($var1) &&
    isset($var2) &&
    isset($var3)
){}
```

can be re-written as

```
if(isset($var1,$var2,$var3)){}
```

but what's the syntax for if *any* are set?

```
if(
    isset($var1) ||
    isset($var2) ||
    isset($var3)
){}
```

Looks ugly; is there any better way to write this?

Comment: I suppose there's no way.

Comment: With the new php7 operator: `if ($var1 ?? $var2 ?? $var3 ?? false)`

Comment: @SamDufel unless `$var1 === false`

Comment: or you could use a sentinel value at the end...  `if ("bubblegum" !== $var1 ?? $var2 ?? $var3 ?? "bubblegum")`

Comment: @SamDufel your bubblegum example always returns true.

Comment: There may be some quirks with the binding precedence around the null coalescing operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass strings instead of the variables, but for fun:

```
if(compact('var1', 'var2', 'var3')) {
    echo 'one or more is set';
} else {
    echo 'none are set';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess one could write a simple function to use, but there's probably a cleaner way.

```
function anyset(...$vars){
    foreach($vars as $var){
        if(isset($var)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if(anyset($var1,$var2,$var3)){}
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: If you're not dealing with checkboxes and/or radios but actual inputs, it's best to use `empty()`. rather than `isset()` This Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236354/php-is-null-or-empty may help shed some light on this, most particularly this answer in there http://stackoverflow.com/a/15607549/1415724 (after seeing your edit with nulls).

Comment: However, if `isset()` is the requirement, then using the same syntax for `empty()` as you did for `if(isset($var1,$var2,$var3))` won't work unfortunately. Would have been nice though and would have made it a lot easier.

Comment: @Fred-ii- hey! thanks for the note, and [I remember](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/62693758) :)

Comment: You're welcome Jeff. Wow... you've a better memory than me *lol!* Cheers

Comment: Well, I didn't exactly remember, but it rang a bell, so [I could dig for it](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/574692).

Comment: Ouuuuhhhh, db comments! Nice :-)) I don't believe I knew about that; now I do ;-)