# How to validate null or empty in php

Tags: php, validation

I am working on PHP, today I got an issue with string null. I tried to validate too many things with GOOGLE, but not the success. So I came here to clarify.

I got value of `$var1 = "null"`

To validate above I tried the following ways.

```
 $null = is_null($var1);

            if($null){
                $var1 = null;
            }

            if($var1 === null){
                $var1 = null;
            }

            if($var1 === "null"){
                $var1 = null;
            }
```

But not successful above ways. How do I validate `$var1 = "null"`?

Comment: `if($var == 'null'){/* do stuff */}` `'null' != null`, `'null'` is a string, which is a value.

Comment: You can't do like this as `is_null($string)` returns `boolean` and so you can not compare that to `null or 'null'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can validate in many ways :

1. By using following php variable handling functions

   - `is_null(mixed $var)`
   - `isset(mixed $var)`
   - `empty(mixed $var)`
2. By using comparison operator `==`, `===` or `!=`

### is_null(mixed $var)

You can use php variable handling function `is_null(mixed $var)` which returns **TRUE** if var is **null**, otherwise **FALSE**.

```
<?php
 $foo = NULL;
 $bar = 'NULL';
 var_dump(is_null($foo), is_null($bar));
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
bool(true) bool(false)
```

---

As you can see `$bar = 'NULL'` and `$bar = NULL` both are different thing. Actually, in one it is initializing with a string, not with NULL.

---

### isset(mixed $var)

It returns **TRUE** if **var** exists and has value other than **NULL**, **FALSE** otherwise.

**Note**

`isset()` only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error. For checking if constants are set use, the defined() function.

```
<?php
     $foo = NULL;
     $bar = 'NULL';
     var_dump(isset($foo), isset($bar));
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
bool(false) bool(true)
```

---

### empty(mixed $var)

Returns **FALSE** if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns **TRUE**.

```
<?php
     $foo = NULL;
     $bar = 'NULL';
     var_dump(empty($foo), empty($bar));
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
bool(true) bool(false)
```

---

### `==` or `===` or `!=`

You can use comparison operator `==`, `===` or `!=` to check whether a variable is null or not.

```
   <?php
     $foo = NULL;
     $bar = 'NULL';

// Using == operator   
     echo "Using '==' operator\n";
     if($foo == NULL)

    echo "foo is NULL\n";

     else

    echo "foo is not NULL\n";

     if($bar == NULL)

    echo "bar is NULL\n";

     else

    echo "bar is not NULL\n";

// Using === operator 
     echo "\nUsing '===' operator\n";
     if($foo === NULL)

    echo "foo is NULL\n";

     else

    echo "foo is not NULL\n";

     if($bar === NULL)

    echo "bar is NULL\n";

     else

    echo "bar is not NULL\n";

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Using '==' operator
foo is NULL
bar is not NULL

Using '===' operator
foo is NULL
bar is not NULL
```

---

The only difference between `==` and `===` is that `==` just checks to see if the left and right values are equal. But, the `===` operator (note the extra “=”) actually checks to see if the left and right values are equal and also checks to see if they are of the same variable type (like whether they are both booleans, ints, etc.).

---

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing variable types, I guess you want to compare a [null](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) value, but you set the var as:

```
$var1 = "null";
```

This is a string. In this case, your third attempt is working correctly:

```
if($var1 === "null"){
    $var1 = null;
}
```

It is using the identical operator (same type, same value) and as the values are identical, it sets the variable to NULL.

If you want the is_null function to work, set the `$var1` to `null`:

```
$var1 = null;
if(is_null($var1)){
    // ok now we are here
}
```

Remember that [`is_null()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) returns a boolean value so you can inline it into the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [A more detail answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15607549/7856807) but I would like to addon if you are dealing with `&nbsp;`.

This would work if dealing with `&nbsp;`, replace it with `str_replace()` first and check it with `empty()`

```
empty(str_replace("&nbsp;" ,"" , $YOUR_DATA)) ? $YOUR_DATA = '--' : $YOUR_DATA;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my way

```
function expDate($getDate) {
    if(is_null($getDate)){
        return null;
    }else{
        $dob = $getDate;
        $result= explode('-',$dob);
        $date= $result[2];
        $month= $result[1];
        $year= $result[0];
        return $date.'-'.$month.'-'.$year;
    }
}
```