# Is null equal to ''

Tags: php

I using this code

```
$dato = array_shift($datos);
while($dato!=''){...}
```

Is it correct?

Is the same to put:

```
while($dato!=''){...}
```

Than

```
while($dato!=null){...}
```

Edit:
This is on the oficial documentation php

> Returns the shifted value, or NULL if array is empty or is not an array.

But my code is actually running

Comment: Did you try it? What is null and what is empty when you read the manual?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between null and empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615747/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-empty)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887897/how-do-i-validate-null-or-empty-in-php

Comment: @Andreas yes i've tried, i'm studing engineering and my teacher said that my code was not ok. But is actually runnig. By the way also he told me there are no booleans on php??? That is not true lol

Comment: Null = no value, '' = empty string. Also you can try it $var = ''; if($var == null){ echo 'var is null'; } else { echo 'var is not null';}

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to check the value is empty in any array

```
while(!empty($dato)){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

NULL = Doesn't exist 
 
'' = Exists but it's empty

Answer (score 0):

You can validate in many ways :

1. By using php variable handling function `is_null(mixed $var)`
2. By using php variable handling function is `set(mixed $var)`
3. By using php variable handling function `empty(mixed $var)`
4. By using comparison operator `==`, `===` or `!=`