# PHP - Are empty arrays considered as null

Tags: php, arrays, null, isnullorempty, triple-equals

The following code gives `TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,`
I dont understand the TRUE response on empty arrays.
Someone has an explanation?

```
$results=array();
// Case 1 : Empty array
$myArray=array();
array_push($results, ($myArray==null));
array_push($results, ($myArray===null));
// Case 2 : Non Empty array
$myArray=array(1);
array_push($results,($myArray==null));
array_push($results,($myArray===null));
//
foreach ($results as $result) {
    if ($result) echo("TRUE,"); else echo ("FALSE,");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Response here : PHP treats NULL, false, 0, and the empty string as equal, see stackoverflow here  [php is null or empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236354/php-is-null-or-empty)

... and empty arrays

Need to be very careful so