# if statement evaluates to true on NULL variable when using is_null()

Tags: php

So I've got a form with a modal, that modal has 3 rows with 2 text fields each, if the user (me in this prod case) fills out only 2 rows, and leave the other row empty, that 3rd value should be NULL.

In my script I've got:

```
if (!is_null($_POST['packageDependencies']['bundle'][2])) {
$packageDependency3 = $_POST['packageDependencies']['bundle'][2] . "|" . $_POST['packageDependencies']['version'][2] . "|" . $_POST['packageDependencies']['repository'][2];
$depends = "<key>dependencies</key>
            <array>
                <string>$packageDependency1</string>
                <string>$packageDependency2</string>
                <string>$packageDependency3</string>
            </array>
            ";
```

}

So I'm checking `if (!is_null($3rdRow)) { //Do this }`, but the variable `$_POST['packageDependencies']['bundle'][2]` is in fact NULL, as I use `var_dump($_POST['packageDependencies']['bundle'][2]);` and I get `NULL` printed to the page, but the `if` statement is still processing as if it *isn't* `NULL`.

`$depends` gets `fwrite()` to an XML file, and when I open it, I only see `||` and but that shouldn't be there as the variable is NULL as I entered no values into those input fields.

Comment: If you are just checking to see if there isn't user input then try empty()

Comment: try `empty()` instead

Comment: @WillardSolutions `!empty()` seems to do the trick, but what's up with `!is_null()` not working?

Comment: There are some great answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236354/php-is-null-or-empty) that will settle your query

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the info, I've decided to use `==` operands to be less ambiguous as one of those posts states, and I'll get in the practice of doing that instead of using `is_null()` and `empty()` from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given my advice, a more complete solution would be:

```
if (!empty(trim($_POST['packageDependencies']['bundle'][2]))) {
```

NULL is a specific state of a variable that involves the way PHP associates the name of a variable with a variable location.  You can think of it like a flag, that indicates a variable name exists, but there is no storage location associated with it.  There are a number of situations that empty with trim will catch that will bypass a check against null.

Comment: This makes sense, as `trim()` removes whitespaces, and if a user accidentally hits the space key within one of the fields but doesn't notice, it won't cause issues. I'll add the `trim()` function in, thank you so much! I learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 0):

Even though `!empty()` did the trick, I've decided to use `==` to be less ambiguous. The answers found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236354/php-is-null-or-empty) are quite intuitive.

EDIT: As per @gview, adding `(!empty(trim($var)))` is the best bet as if a user accidentally presses the space key after a tab, it will avoid any errors.