# Weird behavior with PHP's empty() function

Tags: php, database

I started having a weird behavior with PHP's empty() function. Everything used to work properly, but now it doesn't, and I don't get why.

I have a tbInventory class that represents out products. One record per unit.

That class has a getBootloaderRevision method/property:

```
public function getBootloaderRevision() {
    if (empty($this->cBootloaderRevision)) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return $this->cBootloaderRevision;          
    }
}
```

It used to work, but now, the empty() function returns true even if the member has a value. Here is an example:

```
$prod = new tbInventory($db, 1009);
$test = $prod->cBootloaderRevision;
echo $prod->cBootloaderRevision . "<br>";
echo $test . "<br>";
echo (empty($prod->cBootloaderRevision) ? "1" : "02") . "<br>";
echo (empty($test) ? "1" : "0") . "<br>";
```

I'm loading an item from my database, an Item I know to have a BootLoader Revision. I declare and load it on the first line, then I put the value of the MEMBER itself straight in a variable. I then echo both the member and the variable to prove they both have the value.

I then echo a 1 or a 0 depending on the result of the empty() function for both the member and the variable. Here is the results:

```
01.07
01.07
1
0
```

I'm at a lost here. I do NOT understand why this is happening. I know it used to work, I haven't touched this in over a year. We made an update on the server recently, and it seems to have started acting this way since the server. I was not in charge of the update, but I think they updated both the OS and PHP.

Have you ever seen something like that???

Thank you,

Comment: `0` is not considered as being empty, nor is NULL if this is db related.

Comment: Are there any magic `__get`ters involved?

Comment: @Funk `empty(0)` and `empty(null)` are very much `true`…!

Comment: exactly what I was typing deceze

Comment: @deceze oh yeah? *heh*, okie dokie then.

Comment: Is `__isset()` defined in the tbInventory class?

Comment: Funk Forty Niner, please read again. The member contains "01.07". it doesn NOT contain just 0. Also, empty(0) is absolutely true...

deceze, nope, no magical getter involved :(

Comment: how many more guys are going to ping me here? **I GET IT.** *Jeez*. relax man.

Comment: There ist a pretty good explanation in php documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) (see return values) or you can see some nice answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15607549/3095216

Comment: Dude... read the question... I have obviously read that page before. My value is "01.07". I'm trying to get why it returns true when it comes from the object's member, while it returns false when it comes from a variable... That page doesn NOT answer my question.

Comment: is $test == $prod->cBootloaderRevision ??

Comment: please, can you show where cBootloaderRevision is declared/initialized? And if there is a __get function somewhere?

Comment: If possible, reduce `tbInventory` to the bare minimum that shows this behavior and post that code; this is not reproducible as shown.

Comment: One explanation for the behavior changing without changing the code, is a different behavior related to `offsetExists` introduced in PHP 7.0.5 (released 31.03.16; 2 and a half years ago). I put together a contrived example to illustrate the change. Of course I don't know if it is even related to your question. But here it is: https://3v4l.org/85uiY

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that would explain this behaviour is if `cBootloaderRevision` isn't a "physical" property but is being retrieved with the `__get` magic method, and the class either has no `__isset` method implemented or that method is returning results inconsistent with `__get`. The reason is that `empty` will invoke `__isset` first, but `$prod->cBootloaderRevision` will just invoke `__get`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get.

Comment: I'd have to analyse the DAL, I'm not the one who made it... It doesn't seem to use a magical getter, but these are also not actual members. They are added using a add() function defined in the TableObject class, which all the tables inherit from.

The weird part is that this piece of code hasn't changed in at least a year and a half to two years. It always used to work.. until last week.

I have fixed the issue by using a variable. These properties were badly coded anyway... now the property writes the "member" to a variable, and then I use a return empty($var) : null : $var;

Comment: so the problem is fixed... but not explained XD. By chance, this is the only class in which I had properties doing this. I had two of them, and of course, both had the same issue. I guess I'll find out exactly what happened once I take an hour or two to analyse the DAL. Never really had time to look into it lol. Thanks for your help mate!